# No traces in Invocation Details panel for my dockerized Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm running some Azure Functions packaged in a Docker image.
Everything is running in an App Service Environment v3 and the Function App has been configured with an App Insights.

If I look at the details of my executions in "Invocation Details" panel I only see one firing logs for each function.

[function's invocation details panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESOTb.png)

However, I see the traces in the App Insights logs but two issues :

- the logs seems truncated
- the logs are not linked to any function nor execution so when there is multiple execution/function at the same time it's messed-up

[function traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PflW.png)

I tried to tweak the logger from my python code but it didn't worked.

I also tried to tweak the logs settings from the function.json file and more widely from the host.json file without success.

Answer (score 0):

> - the logs are not linked to any function nor execution so when there is multiple execution/function at the same time it's messed-up
>   logs seems truncated

- The log entries might be split across multiple files. This can give the appearance of truncated logs.

I created two functions in one folder in my local environment.
below is my folder structure and the functions executed successfully.

[image]

Logs status in application insights:

[image]

I am getting the logs of both functions separately in application insights.

[image]

I am getting the Logs in appinsights including invocation Id like below:
[image]

By using below query getting invocation details.

**Output:**

[image]